# End php if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I compare a string from a feed with another variable and echo a corresponding string.

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_file($feed);

foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {      
    $caller = $entry->caller[0];
    $message = $entry->message[0];
} 


if (($caller == $id) {
  echo '$message';
}
```

I want to echo no more than 5 messages, regardless of the number of ($caller == $id) matches.

```
 $x=1; 

 while (($caller == $id) && ($x<=5)) {
         echo '$x $message';
         $x++;
 }
```

That general approach has failed.

I thought maybe I could put the condition in a function and call it a certain number of times but no luck.

```
function myFunction(){
    echo '$message';
}

$x=1; 

while($x<=5) {
    echo '$x';
    myFunction();
    $x++;   
}
```

Comment: how has that general approach failed?

Comment: You want to display 5 times the same message ? By message I mean an XMl entry. Or you want to only display 5 first XML entries ?

Comment: Lets see your complete original code including the loop. Your approach should work, other than the facts that variable scoping and string interpolation are wrong

Comment: While `$caller == $id will always return true.. mot understanding what you arr tryin to` achieve here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, your **while loop** would actually only output 4 results because you are saying while x is LESS than 5, not <= 5. You can leave it < 5, but change x to equal 0 instead of 1;

The second problem is that as soon as $caller does not == $id, your **while loop** will stop. You should only need to use a **foreach loop** for this, not both a foreach to extract the data and a while to loop over it again.

The third problem with your code is that you are writing your caller and message values to the same variable over and over in your foreach. Then, in your while loop, your $caller and $message variables will always be equal to the last items in the $xml->entry array.

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_file($feed);
$number_of_results_to_show = 5;
$x = 0; // counter

foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {      
    $caller = $entry->caller[0];
    $message = $entry->message[0];

    if ($caller == $id && $x < $number_of_results_to_show) {
        $x++;
        echo $message;
    }

    // also, you can use a break to prevent your loop from continuing
    // even though you've already output 5 results
    if ($x == $number_of_results_to_show) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which loop are you referring to?

Comment: `$x` will be always `0` because it is assigned inside `foreach` loop. Probably should move `$x = 0;` outside `foreach`.

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze Oops! Thanks for catching that, editing. It's getting late, lol.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have an array `$xml->entry` and you want to print `message[0]` of up to 5 array elements. Message is printed if `$caller` matches `$id`.

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_file($feed); 

// Iterate through $xml->entry until the end or until 5 printed messages 
for($i = 0, $j = 0; ($i < count($xml->entry)) && ($j < 5); ++$i) {      
    $caller = $xml->entry[$i]->caller[0];
    $message = $xml->entry[$i]->message[0];

    if ($caller == $id) {
        echo "$message";
        ++$j;
    }
}
```

If you want to store results from `$xml->entry` then:

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_file($feed); 
$storedResults = new array();
foreach($xml->entry as $entry) {      
    $caller = entry->caller[0];
    $message = entry->message[0];

    // Store data in array. $storedResults will be an array of arrays
    array_push(storedResults, array( 'caller' => $caller, 'message' => $message ));   
} 

// Print up to 5 messages from the stored results
$i = 0, $j = 0;
while (($i < count($storedResults)) && ($j < 5)) {
    if ($storedResults[$i]['caller'] == $id) {
        echo $storedResults[$i]['message'];
        ++$j;
    }
    ++$i;
}
```

Comment: But I can't limit the xml, I need all the results of the feed, and then only echo the ones that match $id (a url param), and then only five of those.

Comment: I have not seen that you store results from `$xml->entry`. How do you want to store them in an array?

Comment: @user1877124 Updated my answer. Now covers the case when you store all entries from `$xml->entry` and then output up to 5 of them.

Comment: Your `$storedResults` variable should really be called `$formattedResults`, as that's all you're doing here. The only different between `$xml->entry` and `$storedResults` is that you've formatted your array slightly differently.

@user1877124 You are NOT limiting the xml, it's ALL still in `$xml->entry`, looping and reading from it do not modify it.

Comment: @AlexKinnee Yeah, `$storedResults` just represents some kind of storage. In this particular case it is not very useful as the same data can be obtained from `$xml->entry`.

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze Makes sense. You are formatting it in preparation for passing it to some saving function.

Comment: The first way you suggest does not seem to limit the echo to five, it just prints every message if caller matches id.

Comment: The second way gives: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ARRAY, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in..." this line: array_push($storedResults, new array(

Comment: @user1877124 Can you give me an example of your input? It works for me. Fixed #2.

Comment: It seems xml->entry is not an array.  Sorry I did not catch that.  By input do you mean the xml data? It is like <entry><caller>name</caller></entry> etc. Still getting parse errors for solution #2.  I will keep at it, and if it works I will post.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @user1877124 Yeah, XML example would be helpful. What version of PHP do you use?